# Powershell: How to read secure strings from textfile with windows service

Tags: windows, powershell, service, credentials

I saved credentials of my vSphere environment to text files with the Powershell `ConvertFrom-SecureString`. I want to use this credentials in my powershell script using the following command:

`$password4host = get-content C:\shutdown\HostsCred.txt | convertto-securestring`

If i want to execute the powershell script through a service i get errors that the credentials can't be read out of the text files. This seems to belong to the fact, saving the secure strings in text files is binded to the user that saved these credentials to the text files. Only the user himself can decrypt the credentials.

Code snippet:

```
$time = ( get-date ).ToString('HH-mm-ss')
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
$logfile = New-Item -type file "C:\shutdown\ShutdownLog-$date-$time.txt" -Force
Import-Module -Name VMware.*
# Some variables
$vcenter = "10.10.10.10"
$username = "fakeuser@vsphere.local"
$username4host = "fakeuser"
$cluster = "ESXi-Cluster"
$datacenter = "Datacenter"
$vCenterVMName = "VMware vCenter Server" #Name of vCenter VM
$StarWindVM1 = "Starwind-VM" #Name of first StarWind VM
$StarWindVM2 = "Starwind-VM (1)" #Name of second StarWind VM
$StarWind = "10.10.10.11" #IP address of one of StarWind VMs
$ESXIhost1 = "10.10.10.12" #Name of first ESXI Host
$ESXIhost2 = "10.10.10.13" #Name of second ESXI Host
try
{
    $password4vCenter = get-content C:\shutdown\vCenterCred.txt | convertto-securestring
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_ -foreground red
    Add-Content $logfile "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) $_"
    exit
}
try
{
    $password4host = get-content C:\shutdown\vCenterCred.txt | convertto-securestring
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_ -foreground red
    Add-Content $logfile "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) $_"
    exit
}
$tmp = get-content C:\Temp\HostsCred.txt | convertto-securestring
$password4Starwind = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($tmp)) 
$credentials = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $password4vCenter
$credentials4host = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username4host, $password4host
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) Shutdown command has been sent to the vCenter Server." -Foregroundcolor yellow
Write-Host "This script will shutdown all of the VMs and hosts located in $datacenter." -Foregroundcolor yellow
Write-Host ""
Sleep 5
Add-Content $logfile "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) PowerOff Script Engaged"
Add-Content $logfile ""
# Connect to vCenter
$counter = 0
if ($counter -eq 0){
       Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction ignore -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
}
Write-Host "Connecting to vCenter - $vcenter.... " -nonewline
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction ignore -confirm:$false
Add-Content $logfile "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) Connecting to vCenter - $vcenter"
try
{
    $success = Connect-VIServer $vcenter -Credential $credentials -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_ -foreground red
    Add-Content $logfile "$(get-date -f dd/MM/yyyy) $(get-date -f HH:mm:ss) $_"
    exit
}
```

But i already changed the logon user for this service to the user who saved the encrypted credentials. It seems that the service is still not runnning as the specific user or it is not possible to use these secure-strings with a windows service.

If i run the powershell script out of the powershell ISE while logged in with that user it runs the script without any errors.

How can i use credentials in powershell triggered through a windows service without saving them in plain text inside the powershell script?

[image: Windows Service with specific user]

Comment: start a shell as the service user and save the credentials.

Comment: I started a new powershell, made sure with whoami that i'm logged in as the user and recreated the text files. Still get errors

Comment: Actual scripts and error messages could be helpful. "It doesn't work" does not allow any diagnosis.

Comment: Sorry! Strangely it seems to be possible to read the credentials but now i get the error `Die Benennung "Connect-VIServer" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.` When i start the script out of ISE the error not occurs

Comment: So, the VMware module is not loaded. Load it.

Comment: I added a code snippet to my question and added the line `Import-Module -Name VMware.*` to the code but still get the error

Comment: ISE does not get patched anymore and sometimes exhibits weird behavior. If the error only occurs in the ISE, use something else like VS Code. I would only recommend ISE for quick editing of a file, but not for in depth testing

Comment: @DavidTrevor thank you for your comment. The error occurs when the script got executed outside the ISE, inside the ISE the script works

Comment: I got it now but I did several things and don't know which step was the solution. I updated the PowerCLI version (was already the latest), downloaded the PowerCLI components as zip file, extractet the files like mentioned in this article: [link](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/5004y00001ipHO71636506763375?language=en_US), had to set the execution policy to remote-signed again and especially had to cd into the folder containing the new module files and execute the command `Get-ChildItem * -Recurse | Unblock-File`